# ¿Por qué el servicio no funciona en segundo plano, teniendo los permisos?

Tags: android-studio, servicio, permisos, procesos-en-segundo-plano

tengo un servicio que reporta las coordenadas a través de una notificación, el servicio funciona bien cuando lo llamo desde la activity, sin embargo no logro que el servicio funcione en segundo plano ya sea cuando minimizo/cierro la app o cuando el servicio se activa en el encendido o reinicio del teléfono.

Estoy corriendo en android 12, leyendo la documentacion y consultando en la red, observe que se necesita el pérmiso ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, y que se debe pedir primero el permiso ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION y luego el permiso ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, ya lo implemente y cuando instalo la app, he ingreso la primera vez debo confirmar primero el permiso de precisión y luego el permiso en segundo plano todo el tiempo, pero aun así no logro que funcione en background el servicio. **¿Que me falta?**

En el manifest tengo

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

El activity esta asi

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                },
                1
        );
    }

    Intent servicio = new Intent(this, GPStracker.class);
    startService(servicio);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                        1
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Código del servicio

```
public class GPStracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

private Context thisContext=this;

public GPStracker() {
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getLocation();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void getLocation() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisContext,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Permisson not Granted X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)thisContext.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,10,this);
        Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

        gato.start();

        return;

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(thisContext,"Please enable GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    return;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    canalnotificacion();
    notificacion();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

El BroadcastReceiver para lanzar el servicio en el booteo esta así:

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, GPStracker.class);
    context.startService(service);

}

}
```